# WebPack: Module parse failed , babel-loader

Tags: npm, reactjs, babeljs

Soy nuevo en esto, estoy aprendiendo react, pero tengo el siguiente error no sé si es sintaxis en mi webpackconfig o alguna propiedad, dependencia, me está faltando. helpme..

[image: no compila :/]

webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
  entry: 
    './app/index.js'  ,
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: __dirname + '/app',
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "prueba",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "NPM react webpack",
  "main": "/app/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "production": "webpack -p",
    "start" : "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>WAAAASAP</div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Hola @Isako, he actualizado mi respuesta, creo que te podría funcionar. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba cambiar tu `include` por un `exclude` y lo único que vas a excluir es `node_modules`, así:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"          
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Gracias :D http://imgur.com/ZVwaB4a , ya compila :'), era eso .

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado.